# Efficiently export Astropy SkyCoord array to array/DataFrame/file

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, astropy

Astropy coordinates have proven a very fast way to convert between ICRS and Galactic frames. My question is about writing a SkyCoord array to a text file, possibly using a Numpy array or Pandas DataFrame as an intermediary. My arrays are fairly large (~100K coordinates) so efficiency is desirable.

There don't seem to be any methods in the SkyCoord class to export the RA/Dec as any Python built-in data structure. One possible route I've explored is to create an Astropy QTable for the coordinates (which adds them as strings) but this is slow, and will require additional processing to separate and clean the coordinate strings.

E.g.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from astropy.io import ascii
from astropy.table import QTable

if __name__ == "__main__":
    RA = np.array([0.819853, 0.0920091, 1.04977])
    DEC = np.array([-30.8484, -30.671, -31.0921])

    c = SkyCoord(ra=RA * u.degree, dec=DEC * u.degree, frame="icrs")
    c_galactic = c.galactic

    table = QTable([c_galactic], names=["skycoord"])
    ascii.write(
        table, "gal_coords.csv", format="csv", fast_writer=False, overwrite=True
    )
```

Any suggestions for the best way to achieve this would be very welcome. If the solution is generalisable to converting SkyCoord arrays to other data structures, I hope it would be useful to the broader community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Astropy has built-in functionality to handle exporting a coordinate column in a Table to CSV using the [ECSV format](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.io.ascii.Ecsv.html), see the example below. This automatically generates column names corresponding to the original column with the relevant coordinate attributes, in this case `l` and `b` for Galactic.

ECSV is an extension of CSV that includes meta-data in commented text at the beginning of the file to fully specify the column data and allow lossless round-trip of data.  Importantly however, you can read this with any CSV reader (not just astropy) by specifying that `#` is a comment (e.g. `pandas.read_csv(..., comment='#')`.

```
>>> RA = np.array([0.819853, 0.0920091, 1.04977])
... DEC = np.array([-30.8484, -30.671, -31.0921])
... 
... c = SkyCoord(ra=RA * u.degree, dec=DEC * u.degree, frame="icrs")
... c_galactic = c.transform_to("galactic")
...
>>> t = QTable([c_galactic], names=["skycoord"])
>>> t.write('skycoord.ecsv')
>>> cat skycoord.ecsv
# %ECSV 0.9
# ---
# datatype:
# - {name: skycoord.l, unit: deg, datatype: float64}
# - {name: skycoord.b, unit: deg, datatype: float64}
# meta: !!omap
# - __serialized_columns__:
#     skycoord:
#       __class__: astropy.coordinates.sky_coordinate.SkyCoord
# ...
# schema: astropy-2.0
skycoord.l skycoord.b
10.618564158206215 -78.83862258651922
12.320325970465513 -78.28290679292496
9.106328561289311 -78.95458548581124

>>> pd.read_csv('skycoord.ecsv', comment='#')
                   skycoord.l skycoord.b
0  10.618564158206215 -78.83862258651922
1  12.320325970465513 -78.28290679292496
2   9.106328561289311 -78.95458548581124
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer Tom. Do you know which may be more performant i.e. this solution (instantiate a QTable and calling `write` method) vs my earlier answer (instantiate a DataFrame and calling `to_csv`)?

Comment: Making a DataFrame and calling `to_csv` will be faster for a one-off that you are not generalizing or sharing data with others.  If you want this concept to work more generally, like having multiple coordinate columns or allowing to write out in equatorial or Galactic or whatever then the `QTable` solution will likely be faster.  Here faster is not how long it takes to write a single file, but how long it takes to get your research done and write the paper.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I may have been a bit trigger happy on this SO question; with a bit more digging, I found what I was after. Hope the solution is helpful to others:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from astropy import units as u
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord

if __name__ == "__main__":
    RA = np.array([0.819853, 0.0920091, 1.04977])
    DEC = np.array([-30.8484, -30.671, -31.0921])

    c = SkyCoord(ra=RA * u.degree, dec=DEC * u.degree, frame="icrs")

    c_galactic = c.transform_to("galactic")

    coord_df = pd.DataFrame({"l": c_galactic.l.degree, "b": c_galactic.b.degree})
    coord_df.to_csv("gal_coords.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this without using ECSV would be simply:

```
>>> RA = np.array([0.819853, 0.0920091, 1.04977])
... DEC = np.array([-30.8484, -30.671, -31.0921])
... 
... c = SkyCoord(ra=RA * u.degree, dec=DEC * u.degree, frame="icrs")
... c_galactic = c.transform_to("galactic")
...
>>> t = QTable([c_galactic], names=["skycoord"])
>>> t.to_pandas().to_csv('skycoord.csv', index=False)
>>> cat skycoord.csv
skycoord.l,skycoord.b
10.618564158206215,-78.83862258651922
12.320325970465513,-78.28290679292496
9.106328561289311,-78.95458548581124
```

This approach will drop any metadata but works easily.